# Is there a way to parameterize Calabash touch or query

Tags: ruby, cucumber, calabash, calabash-ios, calabash-android

Does anyone know if there is a way to uses variables in a calabash touch/query/etc function?

For example, say I have a variable called hotel_name and I wanted to touch("* marked:#{hotel_name}") and use that in a test step like:

Given(/I select "(.*?)"$/) |hotel_name|

touch("* marked:#{hotel_name}")
end

it is not working for me. So can someone tell me if this can be done and how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are missing apostrophes in your query and `do` in your block :) Proper code should look like that:

```
Given(/^I select "(.*?)"$/) do |hotel_name|
  touch("* marked:'#{hotel_name}'")
end
```

I think it should help :)

Comment: Awesome! I believe this was so simple that i over thought the solution and never considered trying that! SMH!!

#newbieBlues